# Fatal error: Class 'Document' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 4

Tags: php, fatal-error

I want to make test.php can convert input1.pdf become docx file, but igot this error

`Fatal error: Class 'Document' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 4`

test.php full code

```
<?php

# Open the target document
$pdf = new Document($dataDir . 'input1.pdf');

# Save the concatenated output file (the target document)
$pdf->save($dataDir . "output.docx");

print "Document has been converted successfully";

?>
```

may somone help me? thanks

Comment: Line 4 says create a new `Document` with this data. The error says, "what the heck is a document?" The php file that has the definition of `Document` has not been loaded, and additionally your application has not been instructed properly how to find stuff like this. *Probably* `Document` is defined by some library you are using, and *probably* you used Composer to load that library, and *probably* the `Document` class is in a unique namespace. If all those probably's are correct, then you need to provide the namespace for the `Document` class so the autoloader can find it.